# Using where parameter to filter on embedded data_relation?

Tags: python, eve

Is it possible to filter on an embedded data_relation? I was hoping that it would be possible to make request like: `/domains?where={"account.field_2_filter_by": "myvalue"}` or `/domains?where={"account":{"field_2_filter_by": "myvalue"}}` but I have not had success.

For example, each DOMAIN item has an associated ACCOUNT item. The DOMAIN account field defines a data_relation to the ACCOUNTS schema, rather than a dict type. In both the ACCOUNTS and DOMAINS schema, the `field_2_filter_by` was added to the allowed_filters.

schema example:

```
# URL is /accounts
ACCOUNTS = {
    'query_objectid_as_string': True,
    'schema': {
        '_id': {
            'type': 'string',
            'readonly': True,
        },
        'field_2_filter_by': {
            'type': 'string',
            'readonly': True,
        }
    },
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],
    'item_methods': ['GET'],
    'allowed_filters': ['_id', 'field_2_filter_by'],
    ...
}

# URL is /domains
DOMAINS = {
    'query_objectid_as_string': True,
    'schema': {
        '_id': {
            'type': 'string',
            'readonly': True,
        },
        'domain': {
            'type': 'string',
            'readonly': True,
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'accounts',
                'embeddable': True
            },
        }
    },
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],
    'item_methods': ['GET'],
    'allowed_filters': ['account', 'account.field_2_filter_by'],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookups are performed on the endpoint resource (the target collection). This is mainly due to the underlying Mongo database, and to how Mongo handles data. There are no joins in mongo, and Eve achieves 'embedding' by performing an additional lookups on the embedded document/collection. You might want to design you data model accordingly, in order to make lookups/queries more performant. A good starting point is MongoDB [Data Models and Example Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/).

For the record, with [support for Aggregation Framework](http://python-eve.org/features#mongodb-aggregation-framework) coming up with Eve v0.7, you will be able to hook the results of an aggregation query to API endpoints, which might allow for new solutions in this field.